# stagewebview on ios - how can I prevent vertical movement of the SWV object?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, stagewebview

Im using flex  (air 3.9) and have a question about using fullscreen stagewebview on ios platform (noticed it under ios6 and also under the current ios7).

when I have a full screen stagewebview and have web content loaded, I notice that Im able to tap and 'pull' or 'drag' the stagewebview up / down in sort of a 'pull down to refresh' sense where its somewhat elastic in nature and when released it snaps back into the original / correct position.

it actually still occurs when the stagewebview is NOT full screen I just noticed so no matter the size, stagewebview on ios seems to allow the user to 'move' it vertically up or down.

Is there a way to specify that the stagewebview should stay in a fixed position and NOT move vertically?

On Android platform it does not do this at all.

Comment: It sounds like you're seeing 'standard' scroll bar behavior.  Can you show some code?  Is the StageWebView component inside scrollable group?

Comment: away from my machine at the moment so cant add code, but nothing heavily customized, just blank stage with standard / basic stagewebiew  .  Not scroll bar behavior because the amount of content doesnt factor in at all... i.e. if the page is a blank html page OR if the page has a few characters of content or content that is longer than the height of the stagewebview, it still does same... so its outside of the inner  'scroll-able' area of the stagewebview... and its the entire stagewebview element that 'moves'... I'll add a sreenshot of the behavior when I get back in.  thanks.

Comment: I think I understood; but I was asking if the StageWebView was in a scrollable container--not whether the content inside the StageWebView needs to be scrollable.

Comment: no, not in a container just directly  on the stage... I wasnt even aware you COULD put stagewebview in a container... I was under the impression it just overlays onto the stage and uses the height/width and x/y coordinates. thanks again.

Comment: @tarmak It is possible you cannot put a StageWebView in a container... [This is beyond my area of expertise].  Actually, it makes a lot of sense it would go directly on the stage and exists outside of the "Flex" DisplayList; similar to Stage Video.  If so, I apologize if I put you down a wrong path.  I was just brainstorming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});

Works perfect for me